# zclip not working locally on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, zeroclipboard, zclip

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rival95/8QfnA/5/).  zclip appears to work in FireFox and Chrome.  But once I put this code locally, it no longer works on Chrome.  It will still work on FireFox; so I know its not a flash player setting as I have set the settings for my local ZeroClipboard.swf.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some searching suggests there are issues running this on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work. the only thing I did was instantiate it, something like this:
for example I have a link like this

```
<a href="#" class="song-widget">
```

so for the javascript...

```
$('body').on("click", ".share.to-click", function(){
 $('a.song-widget').zclip({
   path: "/assets/ZeroClipboard.swf",
   copy: "<iframe src='http://localhost:5000/songs/1/widget'style=' width: 470px; height: 87px;'></iframe>"
 });
});
```

and thats it

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read, this doesn't work locally because of some security reasons with Flash. It must be uploaded to a web server.